# Typescript compiler doesnt seem to be honouring my skipLibCheck flag being set to true

Tags: typescript

I am receiving a bunch of syntax issues for library d.ts files in my project which I want to suppress. I see the 'skipLibCheck' option is available which I have set to true in my config, but it makes no difference:

```
ERROR in C:\Users\\***\Documents\GitHub\\***\node_modules\@types\leaflet\index.d.ts
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\\***\Documents\GitHub\\***\node_modules\@types\leaflet\index.d.ts(594,5)
      TS7028: Unused label.

ERROR in C:\Users\\***\Documents\GitHub\\***\node_modules\@types\handlebars\index.d.ts
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\\***\Documents\GitHub\\***\node_modules\@types\handlebars\index.d.ts(22,31)
      TS1005: ',' expected.

ERROR in C:\Users\\***\Documents\GitHub\\***\node_modules\@types\handlebars\index.d.ts
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\\***\Documents\GitHub\\***\node_modules\@types\handlebars\index.d.ts(24,32)
      TS1005: ',' expected.

ERROR in C:\Users\\***\Documents\GitHub\\***\node_modules\@types\handlebars\index.d.ts
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\\***\Documents\GitHub\\***\node_modules\@types\handlebars\index.d.ts(99,40)
      TS1005: ',' expected.
```

My tsconfig:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "rootDir": "../",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "noImplicitThis": false,
        "noUnusedLocals": false,
        "noUnusedParameters": false,
        "pretty": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "allowUnreachableCode": false,
        "declaration": false,
        "allowJs": true,
        "module": "commonJs",
        "typeRoots" : ["./typings/index.d.ts", "../../node_modules/@types"],
        "skipLibCheck": true
    },
    "include": [
        "./typings/index.d.ts",
        "./app/**/*.module.ts",
        "./app/**/*.run.ts",
        "./app/**/*.routes.ts",
        "./app/**/*.enum.ts",
        "./app/**/*.controller.ts",
        "./app/**/*.model.ts",
        "./app/**/*.directive.ts",
        "./app/**/*.component.ts",
        "./app/**/*.filter.ts",
        "./app/**/*.service.ts",
        "./app/interfaces/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "dist"
    ]
}
```

I am using the latest version of webpack (3.11.0), should the skipLibCheck flag work here?

Thanks

Comment: How does your tsconfig.json look like ?

Comment: @cyrix - I have just added it to my original post, thanks

Comment: You should add `node_modules` to the `exclude` list and normally a `./app/**/*.ts` in `include` should be enougth. And optionally an `**/*.spec.ts` into `exclude` if you have any spec files.

Comment: Thanks @cyrix, I added in `node_modules` to my `exclude` option but this has not go rid of the errors

Comment: Does removing the `typeRoots` work?

Answer (score 1):

`skipLibCheck` skips the type inconsistency checks, but seems like you have some syntax errors. `TS1005: ',' expected.` is obviously not a type error.